# /dev/bus/usb not created/found

Tags: linux, kernel, libusb

We are moving from 3.4 Kernel to 3.14 Kernel
In 3.4, we were using the usbfs (CONFIG_USB_DEVICEFS=y) and using the following command to mount it.

```
mount -t usbfs none /proc/bus/usb
```

Obviously the mounting fails because usbfs is no longer supported in 3.14 Kernel.
So, I started googling and found that it is now available in /dev/bus/usb or /sys/bus/usb. We are using libusb.so which looks into /dev/bus/usb for the devices.

Unfortunately, I dont see the devices under /dev/bus/usb. How do I get the devices under /dev/bus/usb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

udev is not running on my box, hence I needed to find an alternative to get the usb devices under /dev/bus/usb

I enabled devtmpfs in the kernel via `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y` and mounted the devtmpfs via

```
mount -t devtmpfs none /dev
```

This brought in all the usb devices under /dev/bus/usb

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works for my 2.6.37 embedded Linux. Thanks!